# is there a limit of space for external cache dir

Tags: android, filesystems

I am using the external cache dir, using "getExternalCacheDir" to save very large amount of files, over 2000 images.

On some devices, when there is about 300 mb left in the device, the files in my app are deleted once i start adding more images.

My understanding, is that you are limited to however much space is availble on the sdcard. My question is, considering i'm using the cache dir, which is limited to my app(i.e it will be deleted once my app is uninstalled), could it be that I am more limited?

Comment: AFAIK, there are no documented rules here. You should assume that the contents of cache directories should be deleted at any point.

Comment: so according to that logic, if my requirement is to save many images, I should save directly on the sdcard , using getExternalStorageDirectory () and not the way I'm doing now correct? or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: If you can re-download the images in the future, the user might appreciate it if you stick to the cache directory. If having the images be deleted might cause harm to the user, use `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `getExternalCacheDir()`.